# Storing ID's in react router URL to extract ID and make api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, reach-router

so I need to store two unique ID's into the url and extract the id's in another component to get data from the data base.

This task requires me to send an email with a link to complete a task. If the task is deleted I need to know who sent the task email.

Any information of the direction I should move in is appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
// current setup
const Practice = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Something path="/task/:id" />
          <Something path="/task/:id/:action" />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
export default practice;


// desired setup
// I need to store Id's and make it not break the website. like lets say optional values or something.
// The only required value is the first /:id
const Practice = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Something path="/task/:id/:id?/:id?" />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
export default practice;
  
{ " desired output is = localhost:3000/task/111111?222222?33333" }
{ "so that I can store the last two id's in an array = "['localhost:3000/task/111111', '222222', '33333'] }

//component
const Task = ({ id, action, companyId, userId }) => {
const company = companyId
const user = userId
}
```

Comment: Have you tried providing unique match path params? I.E. `<Route path="/task/:id/:optId1?/:optId2?"> ... </Route>`? What routing/navigation library are you using? You tagged `react-router` but from your code snippets it's unclear if you are using it.

Comment: You cannot have several question marks in your URL. It can be either proposed optional nested router like: /task/1111/2222/3333 or query string /task/1111?id2=2222&id3=3333. The fist one will work as Drew proposed, the second one should be implemented on component's level.

Comment: I'm sorry I think we're using "reach-router". I have very little experience with implementing this task and no experience with reach-router. So I just added /:optId1?/:optId2? and it looks like this will work thanks so much!

Comment: Well, `reach-router` is a sibling library to `react-router-dom` so they are similar (*in fact they've recently merged!*), which explains why there's a `path` prop on the routed components. There's a location and match prop you can access to get and save url/path information. https://reach.tech/router/api/Match

Comment: @DrewReese O perfect! Thanks again.

Comment: @DrewReese why did people flag your comment?

Comment: Which comment are you referring to? The first one?

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I'm assuming the 2 means people flagged because I don't see any other option.

Comment: Ah, those are upvotes. If you hover your mouse over the up triangle above the flag you should see the tooltip "This comment adds something useful to the post".

Comment: @DrewReese I don't have the option I guess there are no arrows.

Comment: Oh, right, it's a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) awarded at 15 rep. You have 21 rep now so you should be able to do some voting now . Welcome to Stackoverflow, cheers and good luck!

Comment: @DrewReese lol thanks man!